# How do I create a Grouped Bar Chart Ordering with a determined Match order in QlikSense

Tags: sorting, bar-chart, qliksense, grouped-bar-chart

Dears -- I have a grouped bar chart with two dimensions -- Region (Group) and product (Bar). In the bar values, I have their profit. I need to sort by Dimension Product (Bar) in a fixed order that I specified using match expression -- Match ([B], 'Prod1', 'Prod 2' and 'Prod3').

I have unchecked all sort options in other dimensions and value fields.

Still, I couldn't get the desired bar chart that is ordered per my specification using Match. It is always random -- or I couldn't understand the way it is getting ordered.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
NavS